# How can I call a WordPress shortcode within a template?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins

There's a plugin for the [*Contact us form*](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-us-form/).

To activate the form, all you have to do is to place `[CONTACT-US-FORM]` in the page...

My page is calling a page template.
Is it possible to add the [CONTACT-US-FORM] shortcode in the PHP template?

I tried it and it did not work.

The **WordPress page** worked, but not the method I want.

```
[CONTACT-US-FORM]
```

**PHP Contact Us template** I want to try something like this, but it did not work.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: [contact us]

*/
get_header(); ?>
[CONTACT-US-FORM]
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

```
echo do_shortcode('[CONTACT-US-FORM]');
```

Use this in your template.

Look here for more: *[Do Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)*

Comment: Thanks is worked <?php echo do_shortcode('[CONTACT-US-FORM]') ?>

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: [contact us]

*/
get_header();
echo do_shortcode('[CONTACT-US-FORM]'); 
?>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the gist/idea?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to **enable the use of shortcodes** in text widgets.

```
// To enable the use, add this in your *functions.php* file:
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );

// and then you can use it in any PHP file:  
<?php echo do_shortcode('[YOUR-SHORTCODE-NAME/TAG]'); ?>
```

Check [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) for more.