# Wordpress shortcodes not rendering

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm attempting to add a shortcode wordpress sites using a custom plugin. No matter how I try to register or call this, the shortcode does not seem to render.

I am using the default 2020 theme from Wordpress to test this.

This is the code that adds the shortcode:

```php
    add_shortcode(
        'test',
        function () {
            return 'test output';
        }
    );
```

If I manually check this on the template:

```php
    var_dump(shortcode_exists('test'));
```

the following is generated on a page load:

`boolean true`

However, if the following is added to the page content, it does not load:

`[test]`

I have also added the following to the theme `functions.php`

```php
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

However, as this is not within a widget (just post text) I did this to eliminate this possibility. It did not help.

Edit:
I also added the following to the page:

```php
    do_shortcode(['test']);
```

This produces the required output.

Every single tutorial does the above, pretty much verbatim.
What am I missing?

To be clear: Using `[test]` in content to show the shortcode inside post body content is the required behaviour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I call a WordPress shortcode within a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293420/how-can-i-call-a-wordpress-shortcode-within-a-template)

Comment: No. I am using `do_shortcode` to elimiate the possibility of a content parsing issue. I want to call this through content as per the usual method: `[test]` or `[shortcode_name]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the test name, suddenly it is reserved, and secondly, print the entire shortcode

```
print do_shortcode('[mytest]'); // [test]
```

---

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test
Description: La la la fa
Version: 0.1.0
*/

function question($attrs, $content = null) {
  return '???';
}
add_shortcode('question', 'question');

add_action('init', function() {
  d(do_shortcode('Are you sure [question]'));
});
```

[image]

Methods to output content with handling of shortcodes

```
the_content();
get_the_content();
apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

Example:

```
add_action('init', function() {
  d(apply_filters('the_content', 'Are you sure [question]')); // $post->post_content
});
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried 4 separate names in case this is reserved (including random strings).

If I print the shortcode, I simply get the name back:
`print do_shortcode('abcdtest');` prints out `abcdtest` on the page, not the return value.

Comment: print do_shortcode('[abcdtest]'); you are missing square brackets, please be careful

Comment: Ok: great job. So the manual print of print do_shortcode('[abcdtest]'); works. However, the real issue is that I want to render in content. Using [abcdtest] in content still fails.

Comment: do_shortcode('Your content [shortcode] and more content') what is your problem? I think you are trying to ask another question, since I pointed out your error as asked in your question

Comment: No. My original question was showing my debug steps. I do not want to use do_shortcode. I was explaining the steps I used to debug it.

The suggestion renders: `Your content [abcdtest] and more content`, as opposed to the output.

Comment: I edited the answer adding as much information as possible, if this is not enough for you, you should consult the documentation of wordpress

Comment: Thanks to Unbywyd. He didn't answer the question, but made me look elsewhere: putting an explanation as to what I found.

Answer (score 0):

This was a custom testing template, and the content of a post is not automatically parsed.
I've actually created a huge amount of custom meta data per post that I was arranging and presenting outside of the content, so I had used the `$post->post_content` property.

To be clear... `$post->post_content` is not parsed, `the_content()` is.

Things now work.
This is a good gotcha.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't matter to me whether you accept my answer or not, but I explicitly indicated the methods for you including apply_filters ('the_content', $ post-> post_content); which you can use instead the_content() which I also pointed out to you

Comment: You sound angry? I upvoted you and commented that you put me in the right direction. That literally is positive? What more do you want?